# Can't add a non-authority node to my private Proof of Authority network in Parity

Tags: parity, nodes, proof-of-authority

I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial) and everything works until I try to add a new non-authority node form another machine. (Point 8)

The authority nodes are running on Microsoft Azure and they are connected to each other (0/1/25 peers) and work fine.

I've tried all the commands and suggestions I can find online, but nothing works. I get the enode:// of the authority node and then use the command

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_addReservedPeer","params":["enode://RESULT"],"id":0}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
```

with the correct enode number and i get result "true"

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_addReservedPeer","params":["enode://2aba3164aee2b387ed20ca917766728ba36853cd52490787778a9dee4a21167de40c936459e054ee0a6bf462e72864d1ad93d9a3aa288481d222c854d43c0e06@10.0.2.5:30300"],"id":0}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":true,"id":0}
```

but then the node is not connected to the private network.

Any help would be very appreciated because I've busting my head on this for ages now.

Thanks in advance

---

From the authority node I get the following:

```
2017-04-01 15:53:05 UTC hyper-client INFO miner  Updated conversion rate to Ξ1 = US$51.06 (2331523800 wei/gas)
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #3 INFO network  Public node URL: enode://21aa6d918053948b0dbb378aeff28ba7900158a0a7ae0a3e9b3b4df060637c19376a7a40e4ab6a1440ac1f8de6d2c2a00887f782b5af832da692c5bdffc3c354@10.0.2.4:30300
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #0 TRACE sync  == Connected 1: Parity/v1.6.5-beta-987390f-20170328/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #0 TRACE sync  Sending status to 1, protocol version 2
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #0 TRACE sync  New peer 1 (protocol: 2, network: 8995, difficulty: Some(524288), latest:1198…fb89, genesis:a662…6e45, snapshot:Some(0))
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #0 DEBUG sync  Connected 1:Parity/v1.6.5-beta-987390f-20170328/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0
2017-04-01 15:53:11 UTC IO Worker #0 TRACE sync  Skipping peer 1, force=false, td=Some(524288), our td=524288, state=WaitingPeers
2017-04-01 15:53:16 UTC IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing       #3 1198…fb89     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed        #3    0/ 1/25 peers     9 KiB db    8 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-04-01 15:53:17 UTC IO Worker #1 TRACE sync  No snapshots found, starting full sync
2017-04-01 15:53:17 UTC IO Worker #1 TRACE sync  Syncing with peers: 1 active, 1 confirmed, 1 total
2017-04-01 15:53:17 UTC IO Worker #1 TRACE sync  Skipping peer 1, force=false, td=Some(524288), our td=524288, state=Idle
2017-04-01 15:53:46 UTC IO Worker #2 INFO import     0/ 1/25 peers     9 KiB db    8 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
2017-04-01 15:54:16 UTC IO Worker #2 INFO import     0/ 1/25 peers     9 KiB db    8 KiB chain  0 bytes queue   10 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s,   0 µs
```

From the non-authority that i try to add without success, this:

```
parity --config /tmp/parity0/node3.toml -lsync=trace
Loading config file from /tmp/parity0/node3.toml
2017-04-01 17:52:37  main INFO parity::run  Starting Parity/v1.6.5-beta-987390f-20170328/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0
2017-04-01 17:52:37  main INFO parity::run  State DB configuration: fast
2017-04-01 17:52:37  main INFO parity::run  Operating mode: active
2017-04-01 17:52:37  main INFO ethcore::service  Configured for GregSimoPoA using AuthorityRound engine
2017-04-01 17:52:38  hyper-client INFO miner  Updated conversion rate to Ξ1 = US$50.93 (2337475300 wei/gas)
2017-04-01 17:52:43  IO Worker #2 INFO network  Public node URL: enode://88a502f2a9face748dce55fa2c59fd749d29339d63378a87da49b15fa6d8d10d4d4d7de25a7b1ec4fb81a28faabf5e3834ae4371df07afdc24527bfc8bec2c36@192.168.1.34:30300
2017-04-01 17:52:48  IO Worker #1 INFO import  Syncing       #0 a662…6e45     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed        #0    0/ 0/25 peers     7 KiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue 448 bytes sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s, 333 µs
2017-04-01 17:52:53  IO Worker #0 INFO import  Syncing       #0 a662…6e45     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed        #0    0/ 0/25 peers     7 KiB db    7 KiB chain  0 bytes queue 448 bytes sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s, 333 µs
```

Comment: Can you run the node with `-lsync=trace` and paste it somewhere?

Comment: I posted the comment in the answers because it was too long.

Comment: Please don't use answers for additional information, you can always _edit_ your question. Did that for you now.

Comment: The logs dont really show any activity. Is `10.0.2.x` a local network? If they run on Azure, can you try to replace the IP with the public one?

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time posting on stackexchange. I tried to run the same command using the same IP I used to ssh to the virtual machine in Azure, but still nothing.